# Callback Disappears If I Use PointerEventData Instead of BaseEventData

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a callback I am trying to implement with UnityEvents.

On my object I have an event system and I have an OnDragEvent.

[image]

Here is the callback code:

```
public void UpdatePosition(BaseEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("UPDATE" + data.GetType());
}
```

Now if I run this and drag the object, it works and its printing the data type as `PointerEventData`

However if I change my UpdatePosition to:

```
public void UpdatePosition(PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("UPDATE" + data.GetType());
}
```

I lose connection to the callback it cannot find it. It does not appear in the drop downlist anymore.

I used to use an IDropHandler and that would work, but I am trying to use the GUI now and I am very confused as to why I can't call the callback I want with a PointerEventData argument?

Comment: I'm guessing the callback delegate is declared in a generic way too make it more versatile.  You can't change argument types and still apply a callback delegate defined with a different type.  Just cast the base event data to the pointer event data inside the method.

Comment: Casting is how I do it currently but I shouldnt have to cast. Its an unecessary layer of abstraction and my question is about why this is occuring.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I answered the why, you can't just change the parameter list of a delegate and expect that it matches the expected callback. The Unity system is probably looking for methods that match the delegate with those parameters, and since you change the type, it can't find them (nor would it work if it did).

Comment: It works with any parameter I want except  PointerEventData param.

Comment: And if I implement IDragHandler it takes the PointerEventData param. So lame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that the delegate is declared something like:

```
public delegate void CallbackHandlerDelegate(BaseEventData data);
```

This means that any methods that implement the callback handler must have the same method signature, including the type, even if `PointerEventData` derives from `BaseEventData`.

The problem is that when using a "generic" delegate like the one above you can't substitute more derived types for the `BaseEventData` argument without changing the method signature.

The fix is simple though, instead of trying to force the type in the argument list, just cast it in the method:

```
public void UpdatePosition(BaseEventData data)
{
    var pEventData = data as PointerEventData;

    if (pEventData == null)
        return;

    //Do whatever with pEventData here
    Debug.Log("UPDATE" + data.GetType());
}
```

Notice the use of `as` here instead of doing something like this:

```
var pEventData = (PointerEventData)data;
```

Which is also legal, except using `as` lets the cast fail (in case something other than `PointerEventData` is passed in without throwing an exception. The null check helps that out because `as` will return the object as `null` if the cast fails.